# RabbitMQ get total messages count that were queued during whole "lifetime" of that queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ queue where n messages should be sent to queue, and I need to make sure that number of messages received by queue is actually n:

I am using:

```
QueueDeclareOk result = channel.QueueDeclarePassive(queueName);
uint count = result != null ? result.MessageCount : 0;
```

but this will give me number of current queued messages, (some might be consumed before this code is reached).

Is there any way to get total messages count received by queue from code?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by number of received messages.

Comment: Total messages sent to queue

Comment: You mean total messages that were queued during whole "lifetime" of that queue?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I mean, thanks

Comment: I think it's not possible. RabbitMQ just does not track this information